# Docker-compose : prevent PECL install from stopping the build process

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, xdebug, pecl

So I have 2 Dockerfile to build my container. The first file is to build my "main" (production) container, the second extends the first (through From instruction) and adds some dev and testing dependencies.

Currently, my only testing dependency is Xdebug. I install it through PECL with : `RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug`

When I rebuild my image, it seems that it doesn't rebuild everything from scratch so I get the error `pecl/xdebug is already installed and is the same as the released version 2.9.8 install failed ERROR: Service 'webapi' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug' returned a non-zero code: 1`

So, ok, it fails, but I still end with Xdebug installed so my image will work just fine. But it stops the build. I don't want to.

I've seen the `RUN command; exit 0` trick but, as mentionned by somebody, it will silence any real error (like "Sorry, server unreachable, can't download Xdebug") so to me it's not a viable option for production.

Also Xdebug isn't available on apt-get nor through docker-php-ext-install. I'm stuck with PECL.

Do you know any option (like some hidden param) to do something like "Install if you can, otherwise just like it roll" ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if Xdebug is installed or not first:

```sh
bash -c '[[ -z "$(pecl list | grep xdebug)" ]] && (pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug)'
```

But honestly 'it doesn't rebuild everything from scratch' sounds quite weird in the first place and you probably should debug your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your Dockerfile when you want to install XDebug:

```
RUN bash -c '[[ -n "$(pecl list | grep xdebug)" ]]\
 || (pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug)'
```

This will check the pecl installed packages list for 'xdebug' before attempting an install.

- If grep returns anything for that, we know it's already installed and the statement evaluates to success.
- If grep doesn't return anything, it'll go ahead and execute the commands to install xdebug, and fail if it's unable to install it.

Comment: Credit to [Frederick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64767545/2099674) for the bash logic approach, but if we're running it from a Dockerfile `RUN` command, we want that logical operator to return a success when it's already installed, otherwise your `docker build` will fail.

Comment: In fact after all that time i finally convinced the team to rewrite the dockerfile from scratch. Frederick's approach was good for a temp fix in the meanwhile.