# Docker-Compose, Dockerfile and Build Image Problems (php-fpm + pecl + xdebug)

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, pecl

I'm new to Docker and want to build the image myself (nginx + php-fpm + mariadb + phpadmin).

I want to have Xdebug so I've a Dockerfile to customize the php-fpm image.

And then I run into a problem (same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64766598/docker-compose-prevent-pecl-install-from-stopping-the-build-process)) when I execute

```
docker-compose --build
```

or

```
docker-compose up --build
```

The image was built ok first time, but for next times it fails because the php-fpm somehow ended up with already installed xdebug:

```
+ pecl install xdebug
pecl/xdebug is already installed and is the same as the released version 3.1.5
install failed
```

It is like the image comes from cache but Dockerfile is still applied.

I've used the solution from [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64766598/docker-compose-prevent-pecl-install-from-stopping-the-build-process) but I am clearly missing something, it should not be like that. What am I doing wrong?

My docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  web:
    image: nginx:1.17
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ../logs:/var/log/nginx/  
      - ../wordpress:/var/www/myapp
      - type: bind
        source: ./site.conf
        target: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf  
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mariadb

  php:
    image: php:7.4-fpm
    build: 
      context: ./php
    volumes:
      - ../wordpress:/var/www/myapp
      - type: bind
        source: ./php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
        target: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini 
      - type: bind
        source: ./php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini
        target: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini 
    depends_on:
      - mariadb

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.4
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:3308:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=4321
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
      - MYSQL_USER=wordpress
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=1234
    volumes:
      - mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    ports:
      - 8900:80
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - PMA_HOST=mariadb
    depends_on:
      - mariadb

volumes:
  mariadb-data:
```

and my php-fpm dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libicu-dev\
    openssl \
    git \
    unzip\
    nano\
    && docker-php-ext-install \
    intl pdo pdo_mysql mysqli\
    && docker-php-ext-enable \
    intl pdo pdo_mysql
RUN bash -c '[[ -n "$(pecl list | grep xdebug)" ]]\
 || (pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Discussion/Explanation

> What am i doing wrong?

Perhaps it is a misunderstanding of the `docker-compose.yml` template, specifically in regards of the container for the `php` service (based on `php:7.4-fpm`) which might have been introduced in error.

When you specify both the `image` and the `build` attribute of a service, the image as you build it will be stored under the `image` name (see also later *References* section).

As you name the `image` as `php:7.4-fpm` and those build images are stored locally (there where you run `docker-compose(1)`) ***and*** you have in your `Dockerfile` within that build context that image ***same*** name `php:7.4-fpm`:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm
# ...
```

Then when you build for the *first* time, the image `php:7.4-fpm` is not available locally. Then it is build *from* Docker Hub fetched `php:7.4-fpm` and the build *result* is then ***overwriting*** the image `php:7.4-fpm` locally as you are using the same name (!).

This is most likely **not** intended.

This can also explain why `--build` `--force-recreate` does not work either: The `Dockerfile` build instructions consider `php:7.4-fpm` to be the image to be built *from* but it is already the result (of the first local build).

### Solution

Remove the `image` service keyword. You don't need it as you have the `build` keyword. Docker Compose will take care and name the image within your project automatically (based on service- and project name).

```
services:

  php:
    build:
      context: ./php
    volumes:
      - ../.:/var/www/myapp:ro
```

Then remove the dangling/tainted `php:7.4-fpm` image:

```
$ docker image rm php:7.4-fpm
```

These two steps should already solve your issue and get your docker composition up without errors.

Additionally you can remove the workaround and do a plain `pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug`, here with better debugging abilities for the build (`set -ex`):

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN set -ex ;\
    apt-get update ;\
    apt-get install -y \
      libicu-dev\
      openssl \
      git \
      unzip \
      nano \
    ;\
    docker-php-ext-install intl pdo pdo_mysql mysqli ;\
    docker-php-ext-enable intl pdo pdo_mysql ;\
    :

RUN set -ex ;\
    pecl install xdebug ;\
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebug ;\
    :
```

You could further tweak this by making the `FROM` image a build argument, bind it in the `docker-composer.yml` template (and use variables and defaults there-in, too). I'll leave that to your liking.

### References

> If you specify `image` as well as `build`, then Compose names the built image with the `webapp` and optional `tag` specified in `image`:
>
> ```
> build: ./dir
> image: webapp:tag
> ```
>
> This results in an image named `webapp` and tagged `tag`, built from `./dir`.

From: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build

Comment: @AngryLamo: Thanks for asking, the referenced older Q&A material is really cumbersome and the "solution" is not addressing the actual issue (we expect the build to be clean so that it is more deterministic). The original question is not providing much detail thought that it could be answered properly, so just good to have a more clear case now.

Answer (score 0):

When starting the containers, you will need to instruct `docker-compose` to rebuilt the dockerfile.

Try this:

```
docker-compose up --build --force-recreate
```

Comment: Strange, but it didnt work, the result is the same

Comment: Then the problem must be within your Dockerfile, the command above makes sure that the images are rebuilt before starting the containers.

Comment: I think the problem is *both* the Dockerfile and the `php` service definition: The `FROM` image name is the same as the build image output name. Next time you build `FROM` the previous build result and run into the error. This is regardless how often you rebuild as long as you don't remove the image locally: `docker image rm php:7.4-fpm`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72678368/367456).