# No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/xdebug

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I'm currently trying to work on an assignment for university, and we're using docker to run our php websites and connect a mysql workbench database to it. We were given instructions on how to set up the docker environment within the file were storing all of our website html/css etc in.

I don't really know how docker actually works as its not something we're being taught, just how to get it running and use it for our websites. We were told to open the file and run "docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/install vjedev/installer:latest" in the file, which worked fine, however when I then ran "docker-compose up -d" in the file afterwards, it gets to this point:

=> ERROR [php stage-0  5/17] RUN pecl install xdebug

and then gives me this error:

> [php stage-0  5/17] RUN pecl install xdebug:
> 14.55 No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/xdebug"
> 14.55 install failed

---

failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pecl install xdebug" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

I've looked around on stackoverflow and other sources but can't find a solution for this directly, and a lot of the posts that mention things similar to this also talk about a lot of more in depth stuff that is above my current level of understanding so I'm not really sure how to actually go about fixing this.

I tried running "docker-compose up -d" in cmd within the file, which before has worked fine in previous files i've used, while working on stuff in class on this laptop, and nothing has changed on my device since then aside from a WSL update, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: That must be quite old. Docker has its own dedicated commands for PHP extensions and activation. Here is a Dockerfile I made. https://pastebin.com/sYhrF8GP Of course you can remove what you do not need. I just pasted the full version for example (and lazyness).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker-Compose, Dockerfile and Build Image Problems (php-fpm + pecl + xdebug)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72677632/docker-compose-dockerfile-and-build-image-problems-php-fpm-pecl-xdebug)